# How to load shared code in a Chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a Chrome extension, that has different scripts for several pages:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://first/page"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "js": ["first.js"]
  }, {
    "matches": ["https://second/page"],
    "run_at": "document_idle",
    "js": ["second.js"]
  }]
}
```

I want to use some helper functions in both scripts. How do I load a second file, e.g. `lib.js` so that functions defined in there are available?

I've tried using `chrome.runtime.getURL` which gets me a URL to the file, but doesn't allow me to "load" it. I also tried just adding the file to the `js` property, which makes the file load but when trying to call the functions they are `undefined`. And I've tried several types of `import` statement, but haven't gotten them to work either.

So, how can I do this without duplicating the common code into both content script files?

Comment: Just list it in the `js` array as the first element.

Comment: Order matters here? That's horrible. Never would have considered that. Thanks for the suggestion!